# Save entity to repository in a read only transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a method, which has to be read only for performance reasons. Inside that method i have to performe an repository update by calling another method which is not read only.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true) 
void generateData(){
    //...generating data and adding result to informationAboutGeneratedData
    saveToAnotherRepository(informationAboutGeneratedData);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
void saveToAnotherRepository(informationAboutGeneratedData){
    // save entity to repository
    AnotherRepository.save(informationAboutGeneratedData);
}
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: In your client code call at first `generateData()` and afterwards call `saveToAnotherRepository()` when you need them both in a series. Your nesting of method calls, in particular each with a different transaction type, makes no sense to me and will fail as well.

Comment: In the `generateData()` method, a large zip file is created, and therefore it needs to be in a read only transaction, because I get a Server Time-out otherwise. The `saveToAnotherMethod()` writes information about that zip itself, an thus thay can’t be called in two separate calls.

Comment: It can; collect these information while you're in `generateData()` and utilize it afterwards in `saveToAnotherRepository(Map<String, Object> ids)` where it's needed.